# How to make sure whenever application runs it first fetches data from database and then from coherence?

Tags: oracle-coherence

I am using QueryHint to set a jpa entity into coherence and updating it ,which in turn updates the value in coherence and database.

However when I again Run the application ,my first fetch is occuring directly from coherence.hence any update on the database is not reflecting into it.

How to make sure whenever application runs it first fetches data from database and then from coherence?

Answer (score 1):

If you need updates made directly to the database to automatically show up in Coherence, then look at the Oracle Coherence "Hot-Cache" feature: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHIG/golden_g.htm

If you are using JPA and you just want to keep the data from getting out of sync, look at TopLink Grid: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHIG/tlg_integrate.htm